# Prevent link from opening in chrome custom tabs, but in webView instead?

Tags: android, android-webview, chrome-custom-tabs, android-deep-link

Is there a way to make an app link/deep link to be intercepted before it is loaded in chrome custom tabs and load it into a webView instead? That is, to switch between in-app-browser (for Web NFC support) and webView (for javascript support) in Android for a certain link?

```
         <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="urlforwebview.com"
                android:path="/"
                android:pathPrefix="/endpoint"/>
        </intent-filter>
```